# PDFlib for php, is there an alternative

Tags: php, pdf

I looked at the PDFlib website and they seemed to be charging a hefty fee for use of the PDF libraries. Is there an alternative open source pdf extension to php???

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are tons out there.

As some have mentioned, there are:

1. [`TCPDF`](http://www.tcpdf.org/)
2. [`FPDF`](http://www.fpdf.org/)
3. [`Zend_Pdf`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.html)
4. [`DOMPDF`](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) - CSS 2.1 compliant
5. [`WKHtmlToPdf`](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)
6. [`HTML2PDF`](http://www.tufat.com/s_html2ps_html2pdf.htm)

And there's a ton more out there if you look...

If you include commercial, I've heard good things about [`Prince`](http://princexml.com/)...

Personally, I've had great luck with DomPDF...  TCPDF tended to be VERY buggy, but had a VERY active developer (which turned out to be a mixed blessing since the releases often broke the API), but then again this was years ago, so it could have changed. My experience with FPDF was that it was very buggy as well, with little to no support.  But again, that was several years ago as well and it could have changed since then.

Comment: A note on DOMPDF activity: it's actively developed, though releases are few and far between right now. The API is stable so you can always try out the latest dev code.

Comment: @BrianS: That's fair.  I don't care about active dev cycles (it's a benefit), but I do care about APIs that are not stable or at least backwards-compatible.  It makes integrating and upgrading a PITA...

Comment: The $3800 Prince license is certainly a princely sum, if not a king's ransom.

Answer (score 6):

The [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) is free and popular alternative to go for :)

> FPDF is a PHP class which allows to
>   generate PDF files with pure PHP, that
>   is to say without using the PDFlib
>   library. **F from FPDF stands for
>   Free**: you may use it for any kind of
>   usage and modify it to suit your
>   needs.

Comment: FPDF is still PHP 4-Code and seems not to be an active project any more. Instead of FPDF you should use TCPDF, which is the successor of FPDF, and will be continued.

Answer (score 5):

[Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) now supports pdf output:
http://we-love-php.blogspot.fi/2012/12/create-pdf-invoices-with-html5-and-phantomjs.html

The problem with various libraries (PDFlib, FPDF etc.) is the rather long learning curve. PhantomJS uses html5+css3+svg+canvas, which have a long history and large user space and php people know html+css usually very well, so the learning curve with PhantomJS is short.

PhantomJS has nothing to do with PHP, but if you have rather new server, it is very easy to install and use. The downside is that Centos5 is not supported, but fortunately Centos6 is.

PhantomJS uses true browser engine (Webkit) for page rendering, so the result should be better than with various html2pdf libraries and support for new techniques (html5+css3+svg+canvas) is better. Support for svg opens new possibilities, that are before achieved only with the most advanced pdf generation libraries (eg. pdflib) and when PhantomJS starts to support eg. SVG filters fully, then the sky is limit.

Answer (score 4):

[TCPDF](http://tcpdf.com) is an open source library for generating PDFs.  Also on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCPDF).

Comment: +1 I had a prefect experience with TCPDF, It also supports UTF-8.

Comment: It was an awesome solution for me since it can generate barcodes and I don't need to use intermediary images.

Answer (score 2):

[TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) is one I've come across. Seems to be in active development (it shows up in Freshmeat.org very regularly)

[FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) also comes up in Google.

Both are free and open source.

Comment: *sidenote:* note that FPDF last update is on 2011-6-18, and support of UTF-8 is buggy

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html) which is part of [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/)