# php_pdf.dll and WAMP

Tags: php, dll, wamp

I have placed the file, what I found in this link: http://www.dlldll.com/php_pdf.dll_download.html

into my php ext folder.

I have added the extension lines in both configuration places. I have restarted my web services.

I have the same error: Fatal error:

> Call to undefined function pdf_new()

Any help with finding a php_pdf.dll that actually works?

:(

I really don't know much about installing extensions other than the above that I have done.

This is for WAMP.

Comment: Does php_info() show php_pdf being active?

Answer (score 1):

You mention setting up the configuration, but it's best to double-check your php.ini and make sure you have the right path for loading the dll:

```
extension_dir = <your_path_to_extension_directory>
```

and

```
extension=php_pdf.dll
```

and check the directory is readable.
However, it's not clear that the dll you're downloading is really the one for PDFlib, so that is one possible reason why it isn't working if everything else is set correctly.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108361/pdflib-for-php-is-there-an-alternative) for some alternatives to PDFlib.

Comment: Well.. with wamp, you have a directory with all the .dll files in called ext. So I have placed it in there, and considering the other extensions like curl seem to run okay, the directory should be okay. Do you know where I can find like the official dll file. I have downloaded from PDFlib 8 but the folder comes with so many different versions, I don't know which one to use. I am using Windows 8 64bit OS with (I think, a 32bit version of WAMP)

Comment: Gnna check out TCPDF. Thanks

Comment: Ok, sounds like your setup is good, so see how you get on with alternatives.